# Why am I getting stuck making IN query with Groovy to run against Oracle

Tags: oracle, list, string, groovy

I'm trying to make an `in` statement with values coming from DB and then use them in another query. DB is Oracle

Example:

I've been beating my head around this for quite some time now. I need some help:

Groovy Code:

```
def myList = []
def myQuery = "select USER_ID from USER_TABLE where rownum < 3"
println myQuery
sql_dw.eachRow(myQuery) {
    myList.add("'"+it.USER_ID+"'")
}
println myList
 myQuery = "select * from USER_TABLE where USER_ID in (${myList.join(",")})"
 println myQuery
def myRow =     sql_dw.firstRow(myQuery);
if (myRow == null)
    println "OMG its null!!"
```

Output is:

```
select USER_ID from eiv.USER_TABLE where rownum < 3
['5xsubmit', 'A10165']
select * from USER_TABLE where USER_ID in ('5xsubmit','A10165')
OMG its null!!
```

I don't know what could be causing this!!

Everything works fine if I populate `myList` with hardcoded values like

```
def myList = ["'5xsubmit'", "'A10165'"]
```

Also, copy pasting the query returns the result in the DB!!

**Update**

After googling, found this [link](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2) So turns out we have to use prepared statements.  Will investigate how to change code accordingly.

Comment: As an aside, building queries this way should not be a general practice in a production environment. Use bind variables whenever possible - it enables SQL statement sharing/reuse. Can't you replace your hard-coded IN list with a subquery that returns the values you want?

Comment: @DCookie this isnt production code. I was just making a script to verify something and figured it would be easier in groovy. It's not possible for me to replace those hard coded values as I am getting them from someplace else. they do not reside in the same schema

Comment: My comment was more of an FYI. It's a common coding practice that can severely hurt performance as the "solution" attempts to scale. I accept your assertion that you can't get the values in a query, but being in a different schema doesn't necessarily preclude your selecting them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you change the line to:

```
  myQuery = "select * from USER_TABLE where USER_ID in (${myList.join(",")})" as String
```

This should stop the groovy SQL being clever and trying to convert your GString to a PreparedStatement (which as you point out, doesn't work)